# Unable to set a registry property

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set a property in the registry and getting a strange error message. I don't understand.

```
New-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Fortinet\FortiClient\FA_UI\VPN-6.4.1.1519" -PropertyType DWORD -Name "installed" -value "5f4053b4"
```

```
New-ItemProperty : Impossible de convertir la valeur « 5f4053b4 » en type « System.UInt32 ». Erreur : « Le format de la chaîne d'entrée est incorrect. »
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ New-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Software\Fortinet\FortiClient\FA_UI\VPN-6.4.1 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (HKEY_CURRENT_US...\VPN-6.4.1.1519:String) [New-ItemProperty], PSInvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemPropertyCommand
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are trying to set is in hexadecimal format. In PowerShell you need to prepend it with `0x`

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Fortinet\FortiClient\FA_UI\VPN-6.4.1.1519" -PropertyType DWORD -Name "installed" -Value 0x5f4053b4
```

Or use the decimal value `1598051252`

Answer (score 2):

The Value should not be quoted, that would make it a string.
The `DWORD` value is looking for a 32-bit binary. This is causing the type conversion error you are seeing.

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Fortinet\FortiClient\FA_UI\VPN-6.4.1.1519" -PropertyType DWORD -Name "installed" -Value 5f4053b4
```

Comment: I did the test with or without the quotes and got the same result.

Comment: This worked for me on my machine, but perhaps our environments are a bit different. Maybe Theo's solution can provide you what you're looking for?